# Get location on canvas from motion event location when scaled using matrix

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, motionevent, scaletransform

Im creating a drawing app, and i have a view that uses a canvas to draw onto. I'm scaling the image using a matrix, and when the image is zoomed in and there is a touch event i try getting the inverse of the matrix and then map the points using the inverse matrix to get the points that are on the canvas from the motionevent points but its not matching up how it should and wondering what I'm doing wrong to get the canvas location from the screen touch location.

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private ShapeDrawable  mDrawable;
    private ScaleGestureDetector detector;
    Matrix drawMatrix;
    Bitmap bm;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save();          
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, drawMatrix, mBitmapPaint);           
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();       
    }
    public Pair<Float,Float> GetRealValues(float eventX, float eventY){        
        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        drawMatrix.invert(inverse);
        float[] point = {eventX,eventY};
        inverse.mapPoints(point);      
        return new Pair<>(point[0],point[1]);
    }

    @Override
    //reads motions and calls methods to set starting and ending points and to   
    //draw canvas depending on the motion
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       //get the canvas location from the MotionEvent location      
        Pair<Float,Float> realvals = GetRealValues(event.getX(),event.getY());   
        //drawing mode where you can draw or zoom in on canvas
            if(drawing) {
                //not zooming mode where you draw on canvas
                if (!zoom) {
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {                            
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            //do stuff
                            break;                            
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            //do stuff
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            //do stuff
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            break;
                    }
        }
        //zoom mode where you can scale the canvas
            if (zoom) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);                        
                invalidate();
            }
        }        
    return true;
}



     public class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        private  float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
        private  float MAX_ZOOM = 10f;       

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Matrix transformationMatrix = new Matrix();
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            float tscale = detector.getScaleFactor();
            if(scaleFactor < MIN_ZOOM || scaleFactor > MAX_ZOOM){
                float prescaleFactor = scaleFactor/tscale;
                scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
                tscale = scaleFactor/prescaleFactor;
            }
           transformationMatrix.postScale(tscale, tscale);               
           drawMatrix.postConcat(transformationMatrix);  
           return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. My ondraw method needs to be like this

```
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();         
        float[] mvals = new float[9];
        drawMatrix.getValues(mvals);
        canvas.translate(mvals[Matrix.MTRANS_X], mvals[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        canvas.scale(mvals[Matrix.MSCALE_X], mvals[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();   
 }
```

I'm not sure why i need to translate and scale the canvas individually in order for the inverse matrix to give me the correct canvas points from the touch points, I'm guessing that

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, drawMatrix, mBitmapPaint);
```

rounds the matrix values to ints because the canvas points i got from mapping the points on the inverse matrix were just slightly off when drawing the canvas that way.